# What type of equipment could generate interference on the 1.6ghz spectrum

Tags: radio-frequency

From the perspective of physics - other than wireless computer network devices - what domestic or domestic or commercial equipment could generate seemingly random interference on the 1.6ghz range?

Either by design or through a malfunction.

What naturally occurring phenomena might cause such interference, either directly or through attenuation.

Context: interference with a wireless device on this frequency - detectable on a handheld scanner - even when all other devices are switched off.

Answer (score 1):

Anything with a ~gHz clock in it will radiate some interference at the clock frequency and the harmonics thereof. Microprocessors and microcontrollers are all over the place these days and each one has an internal clock, so start looking!